# move back to the end of bash history when using reverse search?

Tags: bash, command-history

I keep fairly long bash history and sometimes when I search for something with bash reverse search function(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) I end up at the beginning of search history and I still did not find what I needed and then I would like to move back to the end of the history file. One option is to use forward search function(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) which moves closer to the end of the history or execute `#`, but is there also a keyboard shortcut to move directly to the end of bash history?

Comment: `history` will show you all bash commands made..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the readline function `end-of-history`,
by default mapped to <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>></kbd>,
but if used during reverse searching it exits the reverse search prompt.

## A possible workaround / trick

### Start string search

Instead, to use reverse search, you could use `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward` (default unmapped),
mapping them to <kbd>up/down</kbd> (very useful) in your `.inputrc`:

```
# up-down arrow to search in history
"\e[A":history-search-backward
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

So, after you have typed 
you could reverse search pressing <kbd>up</kbd>
(instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>),
and when you want to return to the end of the history you can use the `end-of-history` function by pressing (<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>></kbd>)

This way *"The search string must match at the beginning of a history line,*"
so, if you search for `ls -ltr`,
you have to type `ls` and then press the <kbd>up</kbd> key.

### Substring search

if you want "*The search string may match anywhere in a history line,*"
you have to use `history-substring-search-forward`
and `history-substring-search-backward`:

```
# up-down arrow to search in history
"\e[A":history-substring-search-backward
"\e[B":history-substring-search-forward
```

This way, if you search for `ls -ltr`, you can type `ls`, but also `ltr`,
before you press <kbd>up</kbd>.

Reference: [Bash Reference Manual – Commands For History](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html).